# Comparing pandas map and merge

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dictionary, join

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': {0: 'EFG_DS_321',
    1: 'EFG_DS_900',
      2: 'EFG_DS_900',
      3: 'EFG_Q_900',
      4: 'EFG_DS_1000',
      5: 'EFG_DS_1000',
      6: 'EFG_DS_1000',
      7: 'ABC_DS_444',
      8: 'EFG_DS_900',
      9: 'EFG_DS_900',
      10: 'EFG_DS_321',
      11: 'EFG_DS_900',
      12: 'EFG_DS_1000',
      13: 'EFG_DS_900',
      14: 'EFG_DS_321',
      15: 'EFG_DS_321',
      16: 'EFG_DS_1000',
      17: 'EFG_DS_1000',
      18: 'EFG_DS_1000',
      19: 'EFG_DS_1000',
      20: 'ABC_DS_444',
      21: 'EFG_DS_900',
      22: 'EFG_DAS_12345',
      23: 'EFG_DAS_12345',
      24: 'EFG_DAS_321',
      25: 'EFG_DS_321',
      26: 'EFG_DS_12345',
      27: 'EFG_Q_1000',
      28: 'EFG_DS_900',
      29: 'EFG_DS_321'}})
```

and I have the following dict:

```
d = {'ABC_AS_1000': 123,
  'ABC_AS_444': 321,
  'ABC_AS_231341': 421,
  'ABC_AS_888': 412,
  'ABC_AS_087': 4215,
  'ABC_DAS_1000': 3415,
  'ABC_DAS_444': 4215,
  'ABC_DAS_231341': 3214,
  'ABC_DAS_888': 321,
  'ABC_DAS_087': 111,
  'ABC_Q_1000': 222,
  'ABC_Q_444': 3214,
  'ABC_Q_231341': 421,
  'ABC_Q_888': 321,
  'ABC_Q_087': 41,
  'ABC_DS_1000': 421,
  'ABC_DS_444': 421,
  'ABC_DS_231341': 321,
  'ABC_DS_888': 41,
  'ABC_DS_087': 41,
  'EFG_AS_1000': 213,
  'EFG_AS_900': 32,
  'EFG_AS_12345': 1,
  'EFG_AS_321': 3,
  'EFG_DAS_1000': 421,
  'EFG_DAS_900': 321,
  'EFG_DAS_12345': 123,
  'EFG_DAS_321': 31,
  'EFG_Q_1000': 41,
  'EFG_Q_900': 51,
  'EFG_Q_12345': 321,
  'EFG_Q_321': 321,
  'EFG_DS_1000': 41,
  'EFG_DS_900': 51,
  'EFG_DS_12345': 321,
  'EFG_DS_321': 1}
```

I want to map d into df, but given that the real data is very large and complicated, i'm trying to understand if map or merge is better in terms of efficiency (running time).
first option:
a simple map

```
res = df['key'].map(d)
```

second option:
convert d into a dataframe and preform a merge

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index',columns=['res'])
res = df.merge(d1,left_on='key',right_index=True)['res']
```

Any help will be much appreciated (or any better solutions of course:))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` will be faster than a `merge`

If your goal is simply to assign a numerical category to each unique value in df['AB'], you could use [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) that should be a bit faster than `map`:

```
res = df['AB'].factorize()[0]+1
```

output: `array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])`

test on 800k rows:

```
factorize   28.6 ms ± 153 µs 
map         32.1 ms ± 110 µs
merge       68.6 ms ± 1.33 ms
```

Comment: I actually need to assign a specific value and not a numerical category. the thing is that my real data dictionary key is something like: 'first_us_1000', and i think that makes the map pretty slow.

Comment: Can you provide a real-life example? Optimization without the real data is impossible ;)

Comment: Just edited the post to contain a sample of my data